# Saving URL to cookie and adapting to button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently looking for something to do the following:

scenario:

user clicks button on page 1-15 and navigates to page 16, user does several actions, and when clicking on a 'confirm' button, he needs to return to page 1-15 (whichever he was on earlier).

How could I do this? I was thinking to simply write the URL in a cookie which can then be read out and adapted in the final destination URL.

Or am I looking in the wrong direction? Some code examples would be helpful as knowledge is limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `sessionStorage.setItem('currentPage',1);`.
then when you need to use this number just call `sessionStorage.getItem('currentPage')`